# Undetermined coefficients, particular solution $y'' +8y' +15y = 4$ vs $y'' -\, 3y' = 8$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about finding the particular solution using method of undetermined coefficients. For $y'' +8y' +15y = 4$, the guess for the particular solution is $y_p(t) = A$; but for $y'' -\,  3y' = 8$ the guess of the particular is $y_p(t) = At$. I don't understand why the latter has a $t$ and the former does not.

Answer (score 1):

We first need the complementary solution prior to making our guess for a particular solution.  If any term in our guess is in the complementary solution then we need to multiply the portion of our guess that contains that term by a t.  This is where the one extension to the method comes into play.  With a 2nd order differential equation the most we’d ever need to multiply by is $t^2$.  With higher order differential equations this may need to be more than $t^2$.
Because r=0 is a root for the second equation, $y_c(t)=c_1+c_2e^{3t}$
 So $y_p(t)=A\times t$

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ODE $y''-3y'=8$, it is an easy exercise to show that the complementary solution is $y(t)=A+Be^{3t}$, where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants (to be determined from the initial conditions). Now, suppose we guess a particular solution of the form $y_P=C$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant to be determined. Computing $y_P'$ and $y_P''$, substituting into the ODE yields that
$$ 0 + 0 \neq 8 $$
for any choice of $C$. The same thing also happens when you have a RHS of the form $e^{3t}$; guessing a particular solution of the form $y_P(t)=Ce^{3t}$, repeating the same procedure yields
$$ 9Ce^{3t} - 3(3Ce^{3t}) = 9Ce^{3t} - 9Ce^{3t} = 0 \neq e^{3t}. $$
for any choice of $C$.

The essence is that, whenever you have an inhomogeneous term (RHS) which has the form as your complementary solution, the most obvious guess will fail. The way to fix it then is to multiply sufficiently many powers of $t$ (in this case $t^2$), so that the terms that we want (in this case is the constant C) will not disappear when you differentiate and substitute into the ODE, thus allowing us to equate/compare with the inhomogeneous term (RHS).